# Retrieving all socket objects in io.socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm looking to get all individuals socket objects out of `io.sockets` and iterate over each of them.

Something like:

```
for (socket in io.sockets.something()) {
   // do something with each socket
}
```

Either I'm doing this wrong or I must be missing something. Thoughts?

Comment: So, what's the problem or the question?

Comment: I'm just curious, what would be the use case for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The official method is:

```
io.sockets.clients().forEach(function (socket) { .. });
```

Or filter by rooms:

```
io.sockets.clients('roomname') .. same as above ..
```

This is advised over the suggestion above as socket.io's internal data structure could always be subject to change and potentially breaking all your code with future updates. You much less at a risk when you use this `official` method.

Comment: This is my one complaint about the otherwise fantastic Socket.io: while there's plenty of [examples](http://socket.io/#how-to-use), there's no concise API documentation, leaving me to guess my way to my first suggestion.

Comment: josh3736 yes documentation is a bit of a sore spot atm. we should probably run a JSDoc tool over our code to create a small API documentation.

Comment: @3rdEden I find it really ironic that this was suggested as the official method, and was promptly removed in Socket.IO 1.0 :) -- [This](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/pull/1630) should add it back...

Answer (score 2):

<s>This may or may not be 'documented', but works:</s>

```
for (var id in io.sockets.sockets) {
    var s = io.sockets.sockets[id];
    if (!s.disconnected) {
        // ...
        // for example, s.emit('event', { ... });
    }
}
```

Use `io.sockets.clients()`:

```
io.sockets.clients().forEach(function(s) {
    // ...
    // for example, s.emit('event', { ... });
});
```

You can use the excellent [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector) to attach to your app and inspect the contents of `s`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Inspecting io.sockets made it obvious to me. I realize my question wasn't clear, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Get all sockets with **no room**:

```
for (let s of io.of('/').sockets) {
let socket = s[1];
socket.emit(...);}
```